# Scaling an SVG While Preserving its Aspect Ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a rectangular shaped SVG that I'm trying to scale up and down using the CSS `width` property set to a number of `em`'s. However, I'm finding that the aspect ratio is not preserved and the icons is cut off along the horizontal axis.

Is there a way to set only the CSS `width` property and have the icon automatically adjust its height while preserving its aspect ratio? Ideally, I'd like a CSS solution because I have a large number of SVG's to update if the solution involves changing the SVG itself (but if thats the only solution then ok).

[image]

```css
.icon {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 448 512" fill="red">
  <path d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: The viewBox is wrong. You really aren't going to solve this without correcting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `overflow: unset;`. The browser's user agent is settings it's own default.

```
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.icon {
  display: block;
  width: 6em;
  overflow: unset;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 448 512" fill="red">
  <path d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: It seems that this crosses the boundary of the SVG itself. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the svg's viewbox to `viewBox="0 0 512 512"` fixes that. Then you can set `width="448" height="512"` to keep that aspect ratio:

I added the red border to show aspect ratio.

```css
.icon {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="448" height="512" fill="red">
  <path d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is cropping the SVG image slightly. I'm trying to avoid changing the SVG itself if possible because I have a large number of them. Is there a CSS only solution?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed - You could remove the width and height settings from the svg (like you had it originally) and then set width and height in css (like you had it). The viewbox setting changes need to stay though. That is cropping the svg. Setting width and height will not crop the svg but will change the width and height of the containing box as evidenced by the red border.